# when i choose option3 then upload folder is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdSeminarType" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" runat="server"
DataSourceID="sdsOption" DataTextField="Option" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdSeminarType_SelectedIndexChanged"
DataValueField="Id" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:RadioButtonList>

Comment: hi please explain more about the question, and use code blocks so its easier for us to read

Comment: all radiobuttonlist came from database in horizontal I want if any one choose option 3 then data will show and also upload folder panel

Comment: These descriptions should be added to your post (use Edit)

Answer (score 0):

So if i get your question right you want to achieve the following:

You have an option menu and when you choose, for example option 3, a upload option is shown. Since you use the tag jQuery i have created an example using this.

```js
var myDatabase = [
  { name: 'Option One', value: 1 },
  { name: 'Option Ywo', value: 2 },
  { name: 'Option Three', value: 3 },
  { name: 'Option Four', value: 4 }
];

var myselect = $('#myselect');
for (var i = 0; i < myDatabase.length; ++i) {
  myselect.append('<option value="' + myDatabase[i].value + '">' + myDatabase[i].name + '</option>')
}

// an option is selected from the select menu
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
  // the value that was selected can be found using "this.value" 
  // if "this.value" is equal to 3, show form field.
  (this.value == 3) ? $('#option3').show(): $('#option3').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myselect"></select>

<form id="option3" action="/action_page.php" style="display:none; margin-top:25px;">
  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: ya but your option was typed manually and my option comes from database when i choose option 3 then it will show upload folder panel

Comment: Updated my code now it comes from a "database"